# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 error message is displayed

Tags: selenium

Code is like this:

```
String txtDatePr = driver.findElement(By.id("--ID--")).getText();
      int txtPrLength = txtDatePr.length();
      System.out.println(txtPrLength);
      if (txtPrLength == '0'){
          System.out.println("Sellable From date value is empty");
      }
      else{
          String[] arrsplitDatePr = txtDatePr.split("/");
          int addYearPr = Integer.parseInt(arrsplitDatePr[2]);
          addYearPr = addYearPr + 3;
          String newYearPr = String.valueOf(addYearPr);
          String changedDatePr = arrsplitDatePr[0]+'/'+arrsplitDatePr[1]+'/'+newYearPr;
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='--Class---'][1]/input")).sendKeys(changedDatePr); 
      }
```

For

```
System.out.println(txtPrLength);
```

Its showing me the sysout value as 0 , but after that its giving an error message:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
```

Comment: The only error message here is `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2`. The other is a display from the application. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

txtPrLength is an integer replace '0' with  0

```
if (txtPrLength == 0){
          System.out.println("Sellable From date value is empty");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

First Thing : It seems you are not getting the text from your expected element that's why it is showing result 0

For debugging you can try below code :

```
String txtDatePr = driver.findElement(By.id("--ID--")).getText();
int txtPrLength = txtDatePr.length();

System.out.println("String value ="+txtDatePr +"And Length ="+txtPrLength);
```

Here you will get the clear idea which text you are getting.

Second Thing : replace `'0'` with `0` in your if condition as you need to compare text length with integer

```
if (txtPrLength == 0)
{
      System.out.println("Sellable From date value is empty");
}
```

Third : You are getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2` because every time you are moving in else condition where you are using `index = 2` right here :

```
int addYearPr = Integer.parseInt(arrsplitDatePr[2]);
```

So Just do one thing, make correction in your if condition as mentioned above and try so it won't move in else condition if there is no text.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are applying "" in an Integer value , remove it

```
 if (txtPrLength == 0)
 {
  //Code
 }
```